# How to pass another class instance to a controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am very new to the controller model concept. I am not understanding how and where to call the constructor of HomeController and how to pass student class instance?

```
private IStudent _student;
public HomeController(IStudent student)
{
 _student= student;
 }

public interface IStudent 
{
 // Some method
 }
```

Maybe, the functionality of services.AddTransient(IStudent,Student<>) I want to understand.

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC Controller Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs)

Comment: You have an client and a server.  The client sends a request to a server and the server sends back a response.  The controller is used to parse the receive message at the server or client.  The Action Results parsing (usually deserialization of xml or json) and the output is in your case <Student>.

Comment: `how and where to call the constructor of HomeController and how to pass student class instance?` Can you clarify more about your question? Do you want to instantiate an instance of HomeController in code? Besides, if you'd like to know more about dependency injection, please check :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not call the constructor of a Controller yourself in your code.
This is what the ASP.NET Framework does whenever it needs an instance of the controller to perform an action that is defined in that controller.

Your HomeController is part of an ASP.NET application running on a (web) server.
A user can execute a function of this application by calling a specific URL.

For example, if the HomeController contains an Action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Info()
{
    // do something, then return result
    ...
    
    return View();
}
```

this method would be executed whenever an URL similar to `http://<server>/Home/Info` is called.

If you need information from a student instance inside the controller, you can pass it via dependency injection in the constructor, as it already happens in your code snippet.
For this to work, IStudent must be registered with the service container. This is done in Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<IStudent,Student>();
    ...
}
```

Such a service may have different lifetimes:

- Singleton: only one instance is created, which is used over and over again
- Scoped: in a web application, a scoped service is created once per client request
- Transient: each time the service is requested from the service container, a new instance is created

Depending on what lifetime you want your service to have, you need to choose the registration method accordingly.